# create element with data attribute using chaining

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

I wanted to create a new element and create a data attribute simultaneously by chaining using `jQuery.data`

So in the example here I want to create:

```
<div data-test="test">test</div>
```

I tried:

```
$("<div>").data(this, 'test','test').append('test').appendTo('body');
```

Without success, is it possible?

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yre9exte/) to play with

Comment: I think you might be looking at [`$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) instead of [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: `$('<div />', {'data-test' : 'test', text : 'test'}).appendTo('body')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also set attributes (and content) for newly created elements in the same function call:

```
$( '<div>', { 
  'data-test': 'test',
  'text': 'test'
} ).appendTo( 'body' );
```

This code should yield something similar to this:

```
<body>
  <div data-test="test">test</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `append('test')` is setting the innerhtml to "test"

Comment: +1 for using the constructor with properties (love that one).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - it is indeed very clean :)

Answer (score 2):

The data-setting variant of [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) takes only two arguments, a key and a value (and the data-getting variant only takes one argument). Remove your first argument to `.data`.

```
$("<div>").data('test','test').append('test').appendTo('body');
```

Note that jQuery's `data` doesn't set `data-` attributes; it stores values in an internal lookup table accessible with data-getting calls to `.data`. If you really need to set a `data-` attribute (e.g., for compatibility with other, non-jQuery code that expects one), you can set it explicitly with `.attr`:

```
$("<div>").attr('data-test','test').append('test').appendTo('body');
```

Note that the `.data` variant can store arbitrary values (because it uses an internal dictionary), while the `.attr` solution can only store strings (since it uses attribute values).

Answer (score 0):

`.data()` only takes 2 arguments, key and value: http://api.jquery.com/data/

```
$("<div>").data('test','test').append('test').appendTo('body');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yre9exte/2/

Comment: `data` will store values as *behind-the-scenes-data* and not a `data-` attribute on some browsers... Use `attr`.